# Express: jQuery Validation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, jquery-validate

I'm creating a web application using Express and Jade. I want to validate a form using jQuery Validation. It does not give any errors, but when I insert wrong values in the form, it does not complain either. It just sends the data to the Express server.

This is my form:

```
form.form-horizontal(#signupForm, method='post', action='')
            .form-group
                label.col-sm-2.control-label(for='firstName') 
                    | First Name:
                .col-sm-10
                    input.form-control( #firstName, 
                                        type='text', 
                                        placeholder='John',
                                        name='firstName')

            .form-group
                label.col-sm-2.control-label(for='lastName')
                    | Last Name:
                .col-sm-10
                    input.form-control( #lastName, 
                                        type='text', 
                                        placeholder='Doe',
                                        name='lastName')

            .form-group
                label.col-sm-2.control-label(for='password')
                    | Password:
                .col-sm-10
                    input.form-control( #password, 
                                        type='password', 
                                        placeholder='Password (minimum 8 characters)',
                                        name='password')

            .form-group
                label.col-sm-2.control-label(for='confirmPassword')
                    | Confirm Password:
                .col-sm-10
                    input.form-control( #confirmPassword, 
                                        type='password')

            .form-group
                .col-sm-2.control-label
                    button.btn.btn-default(type='submit')
                        | Sign Up!
```

This is the rendered HTML:

```
<form #signupform="" method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="firstName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">First Name:</label>
   <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input #firstname="" type="text" placeholder="John" name="firstName" class="form-control">
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="lastName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Last Name:</label>
   <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input #lastname="" type="text" placeholder="Doe" name="lastName" class="form-control">
   </div>
 </div>
 ...
 <div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-2 control-label">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign Up!</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

This is my JavaScript file:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

$('#signupForm').validate({
    rules: {
        firstName: {
            required: true
        },
        lastName: {
            required: true
        },
        password: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 8
        },
        confirmPassword: {
            required: true,
            equalTo: '#password'
        }
    },
    messages: {
        firstName: {
            required: 'This field is required!'
        },
        lastName: {
            required: 'This field is required!'
        },
        password: {
            required: 'This field is required!',
            minlength: 'This password is too short!'
        },
        confirmPassword: {
            required: 'This field is required!',
            equalTo: 'This password is not the same!'
        }
    }
});

});
```

Comment: could you post the HTML as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a first glance, your id's should look like this:

```
  "lastName": { required: 'This field is required'}
```

**Edit**
Seeing your html, your renderd input had a problem with the Id's.

```
 <input #lastname=""
```

should be

```
 <input id="lastname">
```

The same goes for your form id.

**Edit** 
As mentioned below, the name attribute is used for validation targeting.

Comment: Yes, I saw it too. In Jade, can I do this?
`form#signupForm.form-horizontal(...)`

Comment: I have no experience with jade but the basic documentation seems to suggest that

Comment: Although the OP's HTML markup for `id` was badly malformed, **the jQuery Validate plugin mandates the use of the `name` attribute**.  This answer works not only because the broken HTML was fixed, but because the `id` and `name` just happen to match each other in the markup.  However, if the HTML markup fails to include a `name` or the rules are declared by `id`, the validation plugin *will* fail.  [See this page for proper usage](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info).